# INSERT IGNORE WITH INDEX vs INSERT UNIQUE VALUES in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE `Triples` (
`id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`Subject` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
`Predicate` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
`Object` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
`SubHash` binary(16) DEFAULT NULL,
`PredHash` binary(16) DEFAULT NULL,
`ObHash` binary(16) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `PredHash` (`PredHash`),
KEY `ObHash` (`ObHash`),
KEY `SubHash` (`SubHash`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

It contains about 800 Million rows.
Now I want to create two other tables.
One table is Nodes:

```
CREATE TABLE `Nodes` (
`id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`val_hash` binary(16) NOT NULL,
`val` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`subjectCount` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`objectCount` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

That will store all Subjects and Objects from Triples one time (val_hash will become a Key after the data is inserted).
The Question is which of the INSERTs performs better?:

```
INSERT INTO Nodes(val,val_hash)
SELECT j.val,j.val_hash FROM (SELECT Subject as val, SubHash as val_hash 
FROM Triples GROUP BY val_hash
UNION
SELECT Object as val, ObHash as val_hash 
FROM Triples GROUP BY val_hash) as j
GROUP BY j.val_hash
```

OR The following:

```
ALTER TABLE Nodes
ADD UNIQUE KEY(val_hash);
INSERT IGNORE INTO Nodes(val,val_hash)
SELECT Subject,SubHash FROM Triples GROUP BY SubHash;
INSERT IGNORE INTO Nodes(val,val_hash)
SELECT Object,ObHash FROM Triples GROUP BY ObHash;
```

I ask because a key adds complexity to inserts but a union requires a temporary table and i don't know which of both is better in this situation.

Comment: Is the goal here to refactor the schema to be more normalized? Implying that you want the entries in Nodes to be unique?

Comment: Yes. After that step i will create another table that uses foreign keys on Nodes and Properties.

Comment: Have you tried to run either?  Which turned out faster for you?  Why do you need us to answer as question that you can easily answer yourself?  You have not even considered options that may be more suitable, like adding indexes after data population.

Comment: Both require more than one day and on smaller Tripels tables both perform eqally slow. What do you mean by adding indexes after population? The first insert query is performed without an index the second with an index. If I could easily answer that question i wouldn't bother asking here.